# Outputcache conflit with cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, outputcache

I implement output cache in page but its conflict with base page.
In base page I add cookie in preint event

```
                  HttpCookie currCookie = new HttpCookie("CurrencyId", "3");
                 currCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(currCookie);
                 Request.Cookies.Set(currCookie);
```

if i comment  Response.Cookies.Add(currCookie) line output cache works but if not outputcache not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do both. If the page is using output cache then you can't be doing anything that's user specific on it. That defeats the purpose. It can either be cached for all users or not. It can be cached based upon various conditions, such as Param, Control, or Header or a custom function.

Comment: I use global event updatecacherequest in global config..its work